# Select the attribute having different value in different element

Tags: css, css-selectors, attributes

For radios having different name attribute like(code is in pug format)

```
input.radio.(name='value1' type='radio')
input.radio(name='value2' type='radio')
```

how to select all of these with on selector, something like

```
.radio[name = 'value1'], .radio[name= 'value2']{code}
```

but if I do like this the code gets too long for more radios.
Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: use a class instead?  if you have to use the attribute selector, you can use the [attribute starts with selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors#attrvalue_4)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*` wildcard to select based on a specific attribute. Here is a simple example of using wildcard with input elments.
It selects all the elements containing the word `input` in the name attribute.
[Read more](https://tutorialspoint.dev/language/css/wildcard-selectors-and-in-css-for-classes#:%7E:text=HTML-,Wildcard%20Selectors%20(*%2C%20%5E%20and%20%24)%20in%20CSS%20for%20classes,also%20known%20as%20containing%20wildcard.) about wildcard.

```css
input[name*="input"]{
width:20px;
height:20px;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="input1"><br>
<input type="radio" name="input2"><br>
<input type="radio" name="input3"><br>
<input type="radio" name="input4"><br>
<input type="radio" name="input5"><br>
```